# Django system check to warn for deprecated blocks in templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I am maintaining a Django library that has some templates that users can extend. I want to remove some of the blocks in a couple major versions and I was wondering if it is possible to add a system check to warn users who use that block in their code that it is now deprecated.

The official Django documentation for [system checks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/checks/) does not mention templates or blocks at all and I am not sure if it is possible (and if so, how)